# Finding the Sum of integers in a list between numbers from user input in Python 3.xx

Tags: python

```
num1 = int(input("Please enter the first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Please enter the second number: "))

numbers = []

even = 0
odd = 0

for x in range(num1, num2 + 1):
    numbers.append(x)

    if(x % 2 == 0):
        even += x
    elif(x % 2 == 1):
        odd += x

print("Even Sum =", even)
print("Odd Sum =", odd)
```

So far I have it to where it finds the sum when the user puts their input, if the first number is lower than the second number. I've been trying to solve it by putting the inputs into a list.

example:
Please enter the first number: 3
Please enter the second number: 9

But when I put in a lower number first -
Please enter the first number: 8
Please enter the second number: 2

It outputs -
Even Sum = 0
Odd Sum = 0

I've tried everything to my knowledge so far, but can't seem to figure it out. Any advice/input would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If `num2` is lower than `num1`, the loop is never entered, and `odd` and `even` stay at their initial values. Since that seems very logical, I'm not exactly sure what the actual problem is you're asking about.

Comment: NB: you can simply use `if x % 2 == 0: even += x; else: odd +=x`. Since odd/even is a binary choice, there is no need for if-elif.

Comment: Find the lowest one and put it first. Take the absolute value of the difference of both of them added to the one that was put first and put that as the second.

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 you can switch the two values around using tuple-packing/unpacking: `if num1 > num2`: num1, num2 = num2, num1`. Clearer than using absolute values. *If* that is indeed the problem the OP is having.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add an if statement to check if num1 is greater than num2. And if num1 is greater than num2, change num1 to num2 and num2 to num1.

```
    num1 = int(input("Please enter the first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Please enter the second number: "))
    ##-----------##
    if num1 > num2:
         num1,num2 = num2,num1
```

That'll fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution assuming you want to preserve the values of num1/num2,

```
num1 = int(input("Please enter the first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Please enter the second number: "))

numbers = []

even = 0
odd = 0

start,end = (num1,num2) if num1 < num2 else (num2,num1)

for x in range(start, end + 1):
    numbers.append(x)

    if x%2 == 0:
        even += x
    else:
        odd += x

print("Even Sum =", even)
print("Odd Sum =", odd)
```